# "Threat detected" from AVG when trying to run my C program

Tags: c

I've been working on a project I have to do for school,
They basically asked us to separate every question to a file of its own,
so what I was trying to do was comment the rest of the files or exclude them off the project, and when I try to 'Start without debugging', I end up getting this message. I did this before and everything was fine:

[image]

the weird part is that if i remove the solution and make a new one and only make one .c file it works...

I was also trying to remove the "Ex2" folder and made it again, it didn't help.
When I choose move to vault it doesn't find the file.

Edit: I've run a scan and it didn't find any infections on the computer and now that i'm trying to run the program i don't see the threat anymore, I only get this message:

[image]

Please, i would really appreciate some help (again... )

Comment: Stop writing code that looks like viruses! :)

Answer (score 3):

I it find very interesting that your build **failed**. As a result, it is HIGHLY likely that no output was built.
Yet your virus scanner flags a compiled file.

If your code didn't compile, where did this executable come from?
Perhaps you do have a real virus?

It seems the last error, that is partially cut off, is "Link: Fatal Error LNK1104. Cannot Open File".   That suggests that the file is locked, write-protected, or otherwise blocked.
Is anything else holding open your executable, which prevents recompilation?

I wouldn't blame your virus scanner from flagging an attempt to write to a running `.exe` as suspicious.

Comment: Not that i know of... in case it is a virus.. will reinstalling visual studio solve the issue?

Comment: No.   You will have to run a virus-scan and cleaner. (and even then, it may not work 100%)

Comment: AVG just prevents you from running the executable, that's why the build displays as failed.